# Linux command or/and script for duplicate lines retrieval

Tags: linux, shell, awk, duplicates

I would like to know if there's an easy way way to locate duplicate lines in a text file that contains many entries (about 200.000 or more) and output a file with the duplicates' line numbers, keeping the source file intact. For instance, I got a file with tweets like this:

```
1. i got red apple
2. i got red apple in my stomach
3. i got green apple
4. i got red apple
5. i like blue bananas
6. i got red apple
7. i like blues music
8. i like blue bananas
9. i like blue bananas
```

I want the output to be a separate file like this:

```
4
6
8
9
```

where numbers will indicate the lines with duplicate entries (excluding the first occurrence of the duplicates). Also note that the matching pattern must be exactly the same sentence (like line 1 is different than line 2, 5 is different than 7 and so on).

Everything I could find with `sort | uniq` doesn't seem to match the whole sentence but only the first word of the sentence so I'm considering if an awk script would be better for this task or if there is another type of command that can do that.

I also need the first file to be intact (not sorted or reordered in any way) and get only the line numbers as shown above because I want to manually delete these lines from two files. The first file contains the tweets and the second the hashtags of these tweets, so I want to delete the lines that contain duplicate tweets in both files, keeping the first occurrence.

Comment: Does the first file actually contain the line numbers, or is that just for illustration?

Comment: @BenjaminW. no it doesn't. I guess your solution with just sort without -k 2 will do?

Comment: My solution assumes that there are no line numbers, and it adds them with `nl`. The `-k 2` is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk '$0 in a && a[$0]==1{print NR} {a[$0]++}' file
```

As per comment,

```
awk '$0 in a{print NR} {a[$0]++}' file
```

Output:

```
$ awk '$0 in a && a[$0]==1{print NR} {a[$0]++}' file
4
8

$ awk '$0 in a{print NR} {a[$0]++}' file
4
6
8
9
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty close to what i'm looking for. Is there any way to make it print all of the duplicate lines, not only the 1st one encountered?

Comment: Maybe i could loop this command and delete the lines in each loop form the files but i wouldn't know when to stop. When the file that prints the lines is empty i suppose.. But how i do this? I'm just getting started with shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

you could use python script for doing the same.

```
f = open("file")
lines = f.readlines()
count = len (lines)
i=0
ignore = []
for i in range(count):
    if i in ignore:
        continue
    for j in range(count):
        if (j<= i):
            continue
        if lines[i] == lines[j]:
            ignore.append(j)
            print j+1
```

output :

```
4
6
8
9
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: writing python script sometimes can save lot of time !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method combining a few command line tools:

```
nl -n ln file | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 --all-repeated=prepend | sed '/^$/{N;d}' |
cut -f 1
```

This

- numbers the lines with `nl`, left adjusted with no leading zeroes (`-n ln`)
- sorts them (ignoring the the first field, i.e., the line number) with `sort`
- finds duplicate lines, ignoring the first field with `uniq`; the `--all-repeated=prepend` adds an empty line before each group of duplicate lines
- removes all the empty lines and the first one of each group of duplicates with `sed`
- removes everything but the line number with `cut`

This is what the output looks like at the different stages:

```
$ nl -n ln file
1       i got red apple
2       i got red apple in my stomach
3       i got green apple
4       i got red apple
5       i like blue bananas
6       i got red apple
7       i like blues music
8       i like blue bananas
9       i like blue bananas
$ nl -n ln file | sort -k 2
3       i got green apple
1       i got red apple
4       i got red apple
6       i got red apple
2       i got red apple in my stomach
5       i like blue bananas
8       i like blue bananas
9       i like blue bananas
7       i like blues music
$ nl -n ln file | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 --all-repeated=prepend

1       i got red apple
4       i got red apple
6       i got red apple

5       i like blue bananas
8       i like blue bananas
9       i like blue bananas
$ nl -n ln file | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 --all-repeated=prepend | sed '/^$/{N;d}'
4       i got red apple
6       i got red apple
8       i like blue bananas
9       i like blue bananas
$ nl -n ln file | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 --all-repeated=prepend | sed '/^$/{N;d}' | cut -f 1
4
6
8
9
```

Comment: Thanks that's a nice approach. It works fine in my sample of dataset (with 1000 entries) but adds some blank lines in the start when using it on my big dataset of 1.25 mil tweets.

Comment: @lopsi There probably are blank lines in the input file then. Not sure what your real input looks like.